# Implementing Poloniex crypto using Node.js

Tags: node.js, cryptography, poloniex

I am trying to implement the Poloniex account notification websocket API in Node.js
https://docs.poloniex.com/#websocket-api

The command is:
{ "command": "subscribe", "channel": "1000", "key": "", "payload": "nonce=", "sign": "").hexdigest()>" }

The first parts are easy however I am stuck on the sign parameter. This involves
1) encrypting my secret using hmca_sha512
2) updating it with the nonce?
3) converting it to a hex digest?

So far my code reads as follows however the last line has me stuck:

```
ws2.on('open', function open() {
    var nonce = Date.now();
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({  'command': 'subscribe',
                              'channel': 1000,
                              'key': apiKey,
                              'payload': `nonce=${nonce}`,
                              **'sign': "<hmac_sha512(secret).update("nonce=<epoch ms>").hexdigest()>"**
                          }));
  });
```

I think I can achieve the hmac_sha512 by using:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', apiSecret);
```

I think I can convert a value to a hex digest using:

```
.toString('hex');
```

I am not sure of how to implement the .update("nonce=") part. I can partially update this to be as below however am lost on the "update()" function.

```
.update(`nonce=${nonce}`)
```